# API calls using FBJS within FBML page

Tags: facebook, fbml, fbjs

I know that it is possible using an Iframe app, but I haven't found any satisfactory solution for FBML pages. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible as there is no more FBML feature functionality available after June 6, 2012. See the developer roadmap for more information http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/